# How to enable SQL Server instance for all Windows accounts when installed just for one Windows account

Tags: sql-server

On my Windows machine, SQL Server was installed for a single user by mistake and I am not able to see the SQL Server database under Database Engine in local databases.

Can anyone please help me to access the SQL Server for all Windows account users on that machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "all"? As in every user in your entire windows domain..? All with the same permissions? What permissions? You need to elaborate here.

Comment: _all_ here is all windows accounts on the stand alone windows machine (not windows domain) with admin privileges. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: login as SA and authorise people as required however if you are referring to the service account that runs SQL Server then will only be one account either local or domain

Comment: Why do you have a sql server machine that isn't part of a domain in the first place? That doesn't make a lot of sense. And if it does for some reason, why do you have multiple people logging in to that machine? If this isn't an xy problem I don't know what is.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, I am not able to login at all as I am not able to see installed Sql server instance at SMSS login. My problem is to see the sql server instance and select it and login with any sql login.

Comment: Sounds more like you don't have the Browser service on, if you can't "see" it. Not being able to "see" doesn't mean you can't connect, if th service is running.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I don't think that having **EVERY** user have `sysadmin` privileges on a a SQL Server is a good idea. I don't know who has access to your Server/Computer, however, it means that anyone can do whatever they want on that server, including revoking the `sysadmin` rights of everyone else.

Anyway, if you *have* to do this, the easiest way would be the use localhost's Users group, and create a login for that.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN Users FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master];
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER Users;
GO
```

Personally, however, Iwould recommend you, instead, create Login's for each user and grant them appropriate permissions (not `sysadmin`). Not everyone needs `sysadmin` privileges, and it's a bad idea for everyone to have them.

Comment: I might be misleading or not able to present my problem clearly Sorry for that. The real problem is that I am not able to see Sql Server Instance itself in SMSS login screen, as SQL Server was installed only for the user Logged In at the time of installation. I would like other windows users on the machine to be able to select sql server instance when login using SMSS.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't install for a user. It's a service.